# Creating a CDF in Excel

Tags: excel, graph, cdf

I am trying to use excel to create a CDF. I have tried a few different methods but can't seem to get the plot correct. I have data similar to the below:

```
Decision      Score
 Yes           5
 Yes           5
 Yes           4
 Yes           4
 Yes           4
 Yes           3
 No           2
 No           2
 No           1
```

I want to be able to create the CDF so that I can say something like "40% of yeses had a score of at least 4."

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want something called an empirical distribution function (ECDF). This [website](http://www.statisticshowto.com/empirical-distribution-function) describes how to create one in Excel.

I have copied the text in case the link stops working. It says:

> Let’s say you had 50 observations from an experiment. To create the EDF:
>
> Step 1: Enter your data into column A of a spreadsheet. Sort into ascending order (smallest to greatest).
>
> Step 2: In column B, type `k/n`, where:
>
> `k` is the numbered observation (this is easy, it’s just 1, 2, 3, 4, 5…)
>
> `n` is the number in your sample. For this example, I have 50 observations, so I entered 1/50.
>
> For this example, my entries are 1/50, 2/50, 3/50, 4/50, 6/50, 7/50, 8/50, 9/50, 10/50, 11/50, etc...

To plot the EDF simply use column A for x-axis data and column B for y-axis data.

In your case it would be something like this:

```
Decision      Score     EDF
 Yes           3        0.1666667
 Yes           4        0.3333333
 Yes           4        0.5
 Yes           4        0.6666667
 Yes           5        0.8333333
 Yes           5        1.0
 No           2
 No           2
 No           1
```